# Register LED blink without reference to ground

Tags: arduino, led

I'm trying to trigger an Arduino pin based solely on the voltage across a blinking LED. I.e., when the LED blinks, I want to register the blink with the Arduino input pin. Unfortunately, I only have access to the leads of the LED, not to any other part of the circuit (I don't even have a reliable ground to connect to).

I know my multimeter can measure the voltage across the LED, so I know in principle that it is possible to capture the information, but I'm not sure how to build a circuit to do it.

A semi-working solution was to connect an optocoupler in parallel with the LED, but that (not surprisingly) caused the LED brightness to drop significantly, and additionally, the voltage difference wasn't sufficient to reliably switch the optocoupler.

Comment: You could place a phototransistor so it only sees the existing LED, making your own optocoupler. Solutions which use the LED cathode as the ground of the Arduino board and feed the signal to an analog input or the ATmega's comparator (as it may not reach a valid '1') are possible but should only be contemplated with expert care as they can introduce both safety dangers if that could have a high voltage relative to the local earth ground, and also debug hassles - you may not be able to connect a computer to the Arduino, unless it is a laptop running on battery (though USB isolators exist).

Comment: Interesting idea with the phototransistor, although I'd like to have the circuit away from the device. I like the idea of the comparator, too.

Comment: Measure the current through the optoisolator IR LED, and link the datasheet- that will tell us a lot about what there is to work with.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One somewhat more complex method is to use a DC-DC converter to provide an isolated (say) 5V and operate the optocoupler input with the isolated 5V.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fMLd4N.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

A [suitable DC-DC](http://www.recom-power.com/pdf/Econoline/ROE.pdf) converter is only a few dollars. You may have to add a dummy load (could be used to operate a power LED) to keep a cheap DC-DC happy.

Do not use this method without some expert help, as Chris suggests in the comment above, if there is any possibility the LED you are connecting to is not isolated from the mains or other dangerous voltage.

Comment: This method works well, although I did have to use the analog input on the Arduino to capture the blinking. The LED is part of a circuit that is isolated from ground.

Answer (score 0):

Putting the opto-coupler in parallel didn't work well because of the different forward voltages of the infra-red (IR) opto-LED and your visible LED.

[image]

*Figure 1. LED forward voltage vs current.*

Figure 1 shows the problem.

- Let's assume the device had a red LED and was running at 20 mA. From the graph we can see that the forward voltage drop across the LED would be about 1.8 V.
- The IR LED would have dropped the voltage across the visible LED to about 1.2 V. At this voltage the red LED will only pass about 4 mA. (Follow the two black arrows.)
- If the original LED is green the situation is worse as it will only pass about 2 mA.

I think you have two potential solutions:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fOB8hX.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

*Figure 2 (a) existing circuit, (b) series circuit and (c) parallel circuit.*

- Try putting your opto-coupler *in series* with the LED as shown in Figure 2b. If the LED is driven from 5 V or more you might find the brightness is still acceptable.
- Alternatively try your parallel connection again but with a series small-signal diode as shown in Figure 2c. The diode's forward voltage drop of 0.7 V will bring the forward voltage drop of the diode and opto-LED much closer to that of the indicator LED. I suspect that using a green LED in that position would be best.